# CRM 2011 send any request via XHR

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We're in the process of moving a pretty complex ASP.NET application to Javascript.

OData is not an option since a) the page must be callable from outside the CRM as well b) we rely heavily on metadata, which is not available from the REST endpoint.

I'd like to know if it's possible to simulate any kind of Request (the kind of freedom you'd expect server-side) by building SOAP envelopes with strings (as seen in plenty of examples).

Ideally requests would be wrapped in commodity methods, returning Javascript objects deserialized from the XML response.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new entity in CRM called "Generic Request" or something like that.  It could just have a big textbox to pass in an XML blob or it could have actual fields.

Then build a PRE plugin for this entity that does any server-side processing you need.  It could even update "output" fields on this entity that your client would then read as a result.

Now your client can "simulate a generic request" by creating an instance of this new entity.  The plugin does the server side work, then your client could immediately query the new entity by id to get the output parameters if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Josh, this is an interesting solution. However, polling for request results doesn't sound optimal, and I'd be doing this too often to be performing. I'd still like to know if building SOAP envelopes is viable.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to roll your own SOAP messages. I haven't tried, but you *might* be able to add some values to the OutputParameters collection in the plugin. Normally you just get the GUID back. That could save you the second request.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not looking to build "new" SOAP messages; I'm wondering if it's feasible to recreate the existing request objects (the ones in the CRM SDK assemblies). Server side you'd instantiate objects that would be SOAP-serialized, I'm trying to simulate this by generating envelope strings. Hope this clears up my requirement a bit. Thanks again.